# After migrating .net core app: InvalidOperationException: Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization'

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have an asp.net core 3.1 app with AD authentication that works fine. We are migrating it to a new infra setup, with a new set of CI/CD pipelines that use terraform. After re-deployment it fails with the above error (full stack trace below). Any idea what could be causing it?

It uses a containerized build so in theory everything should be the same, apart from the Azure components. As the error has to do with Authentication/Authorization, I have reviewed the AD app registration very closely. I believe I've got it as close as is possible with terraform. Could it be a peculiarity with the app registration that terraform is not supporting? I'm linking the two app manifests (stripped of company-specific data). I'm also doing a detailed comparison of all the differences, under the stack trace.

AD app manifest (old, which works): https://drive.google.com/file/d/187LFczxaReqZLxDrlv7SoWA8nEccUqOj/view?usp=sharing
AD app manifest (new one, broken): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a0ygOo7MvBt6enro3J5DaBvj6lP9HzH6/view?usp=sharing

Additional info that may be relevant - the app uses swagger, which for some reason has its own app registration. I have yet to investigate that aspect in comparable detail

Review of the differences:

- replyUrlsWithType - I'm guessing this is governed by the
  redirect_uris param in terraform, which doesn't let me change it for
  apps of type 'api', only for web, spa and public_client
- signInUrl -
  this doesn't seem to exist in the terraform module at all, it's
  probably a copy of the above (the values are the same in the legacy
  app)
- acceptMappedClaims - ends up as 'false' even if I hardcode null into the terraform script
- optionalClaims - null v an object with 3 empty arrays; I can't
  seem to get it to spit out the latter with terraform

This seems to be it - the rest of the differences seem to be IDs and names. I can't think of anything else that's different between the two environments. It's on two different Azure subscriptions (same AD tenant) and all other dependencies are different (storage, sql db, azure service bus, azure search, etc.) but if there was an issue with these I would expect the error to indicate the same.

Full stack trace:

> Application startup exception: System.InvalidOperationException:
> Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required
> services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization' inside the
> call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.VerifyServicesRegistered(IApplicationBuilder
> app)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.UseAuthorization(IApplicationBuilder
> app)    at
> projectname.WebApi.Startup.DefaultHttpPipeline(IApplicationBuilder
> app) in /app/projectname.WebApi/Startup.cs:line 360    at
> projectname.WebApi.Startup.ConfigureDevelopment(IApplicationBuilder
> app) in /app/projectname.WebApi/Startup.cs:line 317    at
> System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object
> instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
> builder)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder
> app)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
> app)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.BuildApplication()

Next steps I've planned to try:

- Get the Client ID & Client secret of the new app reg (provisioned via terraform) and stick them manually into the old app (it's the same AD tenant so there shouldn't be access issues). If we get the same error - this confirms the problem is with the app registration.
- Comment out everything to do with swagger to make sure it's not it
- Migrate the whole thing to .net 6 - it has to be done anyway, maybe we'll get a better error message

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally, there was a wrong value for the swagger app registration client ID.